# Testing neo4j with indexes

Tags: unit-testing, nosql, neo4j

I want to test my neo4j project with nosql unit. This works fine as long as I don't need a lucene index. Is there a way to create a test database with an index? 
I think graphml offers no possibility for indexes, so I try to use the auto-index like this:

```
@Before
public void startAutoIndex(){
    AutoIndexer<Node> nodeAutoIndexer = graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer();
    nodeAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty( "id" );
    nodeAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty( "refname" );
    nodeAutoIndexer.setEnabled(true);
}
```

this doesn't work for me.
Is there another way to implement the auto-index?

Best regards
Jan

Answer (score 1):

generally , two ways.

1. either you use the `geoff` xml export format
2. or use your graphml, but set up autoindexing on the server side using the `conf/server.properties` file. there, set up these rows:

   node_auto_indexing=true
   node_keys_indexable=id,refname

restart the db and do the graphml import (assuming the imported nodes have `id` and `refname` as their properties - in case you need a general id of the neo4j db and not your unique one, there is no need to specify the id as an index.).